# update a list after item is removed

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a function that updates the style of the list based on which number element it is in the list, so 1-5 are all styled differently.

I have it working with just remove, but I want to fade out then remove the item and then run the update list function. For some reason (not sure why) if I use fadeOut then call remove after it has been faded out, it wont update the list but if i just use .remove() it works

```
    // add classes to each list
    function updateListClasses() {
        var listClasses = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"];
        var numberOfAnswers = $(".answers li").size();
        $(".draggable").each(function() {
            //alert("updating")
            $(this).find("li").removeClass();
            $("li").each(function(index){
                $(this).addClass(listClasses[index]);
            })
        })
    };

  function removeParent() { 
    $(this).parent().fadeOut( function() {
        $(this).remove(function(){
             updateListClasses();
        });
    }); 

  };

  $('.draggable li').on("click",".close", removeParent);
```

just doing this works, but it is a bit too abrasive without the fade:

```
  function removeParent() { 
    $(this).parent().remove(); 
    updateListClasses();
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove()` does not take a callback:

```
  function removeParent() { 
    $(this).parent().fadeOut( function() {
        $(this).remove();
        updateListClasses();
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: ah, just looked at documentation, you are correct. Must have just assumed it had a callback. works well.